# Помогите с поразрядной сортировкой, нужно сделать через массив очередей

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка, структуры, очередь

Помогите, программа работает, но на мой взгляд, она совсем не оптимальна и вообще быдло-код... Укажите на ошибки, и как лучше сделать. А так же помогите, пожалуйста, как вместо кучи очередей сделать массив очередей, заранее спасибо...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define QMAX 100

struct queue {
    int qu[QMAX];
    int rear, frnt;
};

void outputmas(int *mass, int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", mass[i]); //вывод сгенерированного массива 
    printf("\n");
}


void init(struct queue *q) {
    q->frnt = 1;
    q->rear = 0;
    return;
}

void insert(struct queue *q, int x) {
    if (q->rear < QMAX - 1) {
        q->rear++;
        q->qu[q->rear] = x;
    }
    else
        printf("Очередь полна!\n");
    return;
}

int isempty(struct queue *q) {
    if (q->rear < q->frnt)
        return(1);
    else
        return(0);
}

void print(struct queue *q) {
    int h;
    if (isempty(q) == 1) {
        printf("Очередь пуста!\n");
        return;
    }
    for (h = q->frnt; h <= q->rear; h++)
        printf("%d ", q->qu[h]);
    return;
}

int remove(struct queue *q) {
    int x, h;
    if (isempty(q) == 1) {
        printf("Очередь пуста!\n");
        return(0);
    }
    x = q->qu[q->frnt];
    for (h = q->frnt; h < q->rear; h++) {
        q->qu[h] = q->qu[h + 1];
    }
    q->rear--;
    return(x);
}

int stepen(int num, int n)
{
    int i, num1;
    num1 = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        num1 = num1*num;
    }

    return (num1);

}

int run(int num, int run) {
    int x;


    x = num%stepen(10, run + 1) / stepen(10, run);

    return(x);

    getchar();
}
int sort(int *mass, int *massq ,int number_of_el, int runn)
{
    struct queue  *q0,*q1,*q2,*q3,*q4,*q5,*q6,*q7,*q8,*q9;
    int razr;
    q0 = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    q1 = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    q2 = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    q3 = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    q4 = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    q5 = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    q6 = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    q7 = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    q8 = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    q9 = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    init(q0);
    init(q1);
    init(q2);
    init(q3);
    init(q4);
    init(q5);
    init(q6);
    init(q7);
    init(q8);
    init(q9);
    for (int el = 0; el < number_of_el; el++)
    {
        razr = run(mass[el], runn);

        switch (razr)
        {
        case 0:
            insert(q0, mass[el]);
            break;
        case 1:
            insert(q1, mass[el]);
            break;
        case 2:
            insert(q2, mass[el]);
            break;
        case 3:
            insert(q3, mass[el]);
            break;
        case 4:
            insert(q4, mass[el]);
            break;
        case 5:
            insert(q5, mass[el]);
            break;
        case 6:
            insert(q6, mass[el]);
            break;
        case 7:
            insert(q7, mass[el]);
            break;
        case 8:
            insert(q8, mass[el]);
            break;
        case 9:
            insert(q9, mass[el]);
            break;
        }



    }

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_el; i++)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            if (!isempty(q0))
            {
                massq[i] = remove(q0);
                i++;

            }
            else
                break;
        }
        for (;;)
        {
            if (!isempty(q1))
            {
                massq[i] = remove(q1);
                i++;

            }
            else
                break;
        }
        for (;;)
        {
            if (!isempty(q2))
            {
                massq[i] = remove(q2);
                i++;

            }
            else
                break;
        }
        for (;;)
        {
            if (!isempty(q3))
            {
                massq[i] = remove(q3);
                i++;

            }
            else
                break;
        }
        for (;;)
        {
            if (!isempty(q4))
            {
                massq[i] = remove(q4);
                i++;

            }
            else
                break;
        }
        for (;;)
        {
            if (!isempty(q5))
            {
                massq[i] = remove(q5);
                i++;

            }
            else
                break;
        }
        for (;;)
        {
            if (!isempty(q6))
            {
                massq[i] = remove(q6);
                i++;

            }
            else
                break;
        }
        for (;;)
        {
            if (!isempty(q7))
            {
                massq[i] = remove(q7);
                i++;

            }
            else
                break;
        }
        for (;;)
        {
            if (!isempty(q8))
            {
                massq[i] = remove(q8);
                i++;

            }
            else
                break;
        }
        for (;;)
        {
            if (!isempty(q9))
            {
                massq[i] = remove(q9);
                i++;

            }
            else
                break;
        }

    }
    mass = massq;
    outputmas(massq, number_of_el);
    if (runn < 2)
    {
        runn++;
        sort(mass, massq, number_of_el, runn);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Rus");
    int n=12, i, algorythm, min=1, max=900, ra, moveNum, runn=0;
    ra = max - min + 1;

    int *mass = new int[n];
    int *massq = new int[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mass[i] = rand() % ra + min;

    }
    printf("Случайный массив: ");
    outputmas(mass, n);
    sort(mass, massq, n, runn);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Писать циклы с *else break;* уж очень странно. Выделить память можно одним махом на всё: `x = calloc(n, sizeof(*x));` (если я правильно помню порядок аргументов).  Все эти повторения можно свернуть в 10-15 строк кода.

Comment: Я не понял, как все это сделать, и куда писать x=calloc... (Ну, я понимаю, что там будет не x)Можете, пожалуйста подробнее объяснить, очень прошу?

Comment: Простите, делать за вас я точно не буду. Хотите научиться -- учитесь, хотите результат -- наймите кого-то, кто сделает.

Comment: Тогда прошу прощения, буду дальше пытаться разбираться. Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из грубых ошибок:

1. У вас смесь С и С++ (используете оператор `new`);
2. Ваша функция `remove` перекрывает стандартную функцию из [stdio.h](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdio.h/remove);
3. Вместо `while` использована странная конструкция с бесконечным `for`, `if` и `break`;
4. Есть утечки памяти (каждому вызову `malloc` должен соответствовать вызов `free`);
5. Есть неиспользуемые переменные.

Что касается массива структур, то он создаётся очень просто:

```
static const int q_count = 10;    
queue_s *q = malloc(sizeof(queue_s) * q_count);
```

Ну, и имея на руках массив структур, можно избавиться от повторяющегося кода, обращаясь к ним по индексу. Обратите внимание, что используется операция взятия адреса структуры `&q[i]` при передачи её в функцию, потому как `q[i]` это собственно и есть i-я структура (не указатель).

Отрефакторенный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define QMAX 100

typedef struct {
    int qu[QMAX];
    int rear, frnt;
} queue_s;

void outputmas(int *mass, int n)
{    
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", mass[i]); //вывод сгенерированного массива 
    printf("\n");
}


void init(queue_s *q) {
    q->frnt = 1;
    q->rear = 0;
}

void insert(queue_s *q, int x) {
    if (q->rear < QMAX - 1) {
        q->rear++;
        q->qu[q->rear] = x;
    }
    else
        printf("Очередь полна!\n");
}

bool isempty(queue_s *q) {
    return q->rear < q->frnt;
}

void print(queue_s *q) {    
    if (isempty(q)) {
        printf("Очередь пуста!\n");
    } else {
        for (int h = q->frnt; h <= q->rear; h++)
            printf("%d ", q->qu[h]);        
    }
}

int qremove(queue_s *q) {    
    if (isempty(q)) {
        printf("Очередь пуста!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int x = q->qu[q->frnt];

    for (int h = q->frnt; h < q->rear; h++) {
        q->qu[h] = q->qu[h + 1];
    }

    q->rear--;

    return x;
}

int stepen(int num, int n)
{    
    int num1 = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        num1 *= num;
    }
    return num1;
}

int run(int num, int run) {    
    return num % stepen(10, run + 1) / stepen(10, run);
}

int sort(int *mass, int *massq ,int number_of_el, int runn)
{
    static const int q_count = 10;    
    queue_s *q = malloc(sizeof(queue_s) * q_count);

    for (int i = 0; i < q_count; i++) {        
        init(&q[i]);
    }

    for (int el = 0; el < number_of_el; el++) {

        int razr = run(mass[el], runn);

        if (razr >= 0 && razr < q_count) {
            insert(&q[razr], mass[el]);        
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_el; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < q_count; j++) {
            while ( !isempty(&q[j]) ) {
                massq[i] = qremove(&q[j]);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    free(q);

    mass = massq;
    outputmas(massq, number_of_el);

    if (runn < 2) {
        runn++;
        sort(mass, massq, number_of_el, runn);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Rus");

    int n=12, min=1, max=900, runn=0;
    int ra = max - min + 1;

    int *mass = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    int *massq = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        mass[i] = rand() % ra + min;
    }

    printf("Случайный массив: ");
    outputmas(mass, n);
    sort(mass, massq, n, runn);

    free(mass);
    free(massq);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *calloc()* всё-таки чуть лучше.

Comment: @0andriy Наоборот, делает лишнее обнуление памяти.

Comment: Кстати, далеко не всегда. Если вы из неё будете читать, то не факт даже, что из выделенной памяти. Почитайте на досуге: https://vorpus.org/blog/why-does-calloc-exist/

Comment: @0andriy Не всегда, но тут выделяется 408*10 = 4Кб, а на таких размерах `calloc` эквивалентен `malloc` + `memset`. Так что в этом конкретном случае, эта функция будет делать лишнее обнуление памяти.